# java.lang.IllegalStateException: AssetManager has been finalized

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

I went to sleep yesterday with my app working and today when I tried to run it won't start at all. As soon as I try to open it crashes with a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`. I've gone several commits back in my code just to rule out it was something I did recently and still. This makes no sense, how can an app just stop working over night? I've looked for the error in the internet and there is not a lot of useful information about it. Is this really an odd error?

Here's the complete stack trace:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: AssetManager has been finalized!
>                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1439)
>                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1947)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3583)
>                                                          at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.startActivity(Launcher.java:2442)
>                                                          at com.android.launcher2.Launcher.startActivitySafely(Launcher.java:2469)
>                                                          at com.android.launcher2.AppsCustomizePagedView.onClick(AppsCustomizePagedView.java:584)
>                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
>                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Since like I said it doesn't seem to be anything that I did I'm not sure what code to post. But given that the app crashes on start here's the code for the two main classes that are supposed to start first:

**App**

```
public class App extends Application {

  private static App instance;
  private static final String TAG = "Starter";

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    instance = this;
    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    //TODO: Register subclasses
//    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Challenge.class);

    //Parse server
    Log.d(TAG, "Initializing Parse");
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId(getString(R.string.parse_app_id))
            .clientKey(getString(R.string.parse_client_key))
            .server(getString(R.string.server_address)).build()
    );

    //Facebook
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null)
      ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    Log.d(TAG, "Parse ready");
  }

  public static App getInstance(){
    return instance;
  }
}
```

**SplashActivity**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Splash";
    private boolean firstTime = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Hide title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        firstTime = getSharedPreferences(Constants.GENERAL_SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getBoolean(Constants.FIRSTTIME, true);


        if (isLoggedIn())
            if (firstTime)
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, FirstTimeActivity.class));
            else
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));

        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Calling Home");
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        String parseSession = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getSessionToken();
        return parseSession != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add code to the question.

Comment: @LunarWatcher I wasn't sure what code to post since it doesn't seem to be something I did. I just posted the two classes that are supposed to run on app start. See edited question.

Comment: See my answer @Mauricio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your stacktrace links [to this class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/Launcher.java) in the AOSP.

I think this crash **has nothing to do with your app**, but as an error in the Launcher class. Try installing from USB debugging and see if that works.

But there are still some details that are blurry. These lines are (from bottom of the stacktrace to the top) the lines that cause problems in com.android.launcher2 package:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/android-4.2.2_r1/src/com/android/launcher2/AppsCustomizePagedView.java#584

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/Launcher.java#2469

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/Launcher.java#2442

From this error, I assume you are using a Nexus or Pixel (or any device with **the unaltered source code**, meaning stock android.).

From what I can tell from this error, this is **not an error related to your app**. It appears to be an issue with the launcher you are using. Try installing from USB debugging, or change launcher, and see if that works. Try rebooting your device as well.

Further, from what I see of your code, there are **no parcelable classes** in use

Comment: Well I rebooted my device and worked, but I still don't understand why this happened. Might this happen when the app is in production? or is just on debug? I'm testing on a BLU Studio 5.0 LTE.

Comment: Not sure. It can probably happen in both production(production, alpha and beta) and debug. As it has nothing to do with your app, but the launcher, it can also happen to any other app as well

Answer (score 1):

This error can also be caused when **Instant Run** loses connection with the Android Emulator as a result of which new app changes are not persisted in the emulator.

Running the app again will solve the issue.